# Count of System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
ViewBag.EquipmentList = myInventoryEntities.p_Configurable_Equipment_Request_Select(Address_ID, false).Select(c => new { Value = c.Quantity + " " + c.Device_Name + " (s)", ID = c.Device_ID.ToString() }).ToList();
```

In Razor i want to do the following

```
@ViewBag.EquipmentList.Count
```

But Count is always == 1

I know i can iterate in a foreach but would rather a more direct approach.

Perhaps I am conceptually off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, so now it seems like you've got past `Count` not executing:

> But Count is always == 1

Sounds like you're always fetching a list with exactly one entry in. If that's unexpected, you should look at *why* you're only getting a single entry - start with debugging into the code... this doesn't sound like a Razor problem at all.

---

If your value were *really* a `List<T>` for some `T`, I believe it should be fine. The expression `ViewBag.EquipmentList.Count` would evaluate dynamically at every point.

In other words, if you're really, really using the assignment code shown, it should be okay.

If, however, the value is just some implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which *doesn't* expose a `Count` property, then you'd need to use the `Enumerable.Count()` extension method - and you can't use normal "extension method syntax" with dynamic typing. One simple fix would be to use:

```
Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.EquipmentList)
```

... which will still use dynamic typing for the *argument* to `Enumerable.Count`, but it won't have to find the `Count()` method as an extension method.

Alternatively, make sure that your value really is a `List<T>`. If it's actually an array, you should be able to change the code to use the `Length` property instead.

Comment: good eye on the typo, but still same error, the typo only existing on my post

Comment: @Pinch: Well was anything *else* in your post incorrect? Are you *really* calling ToList?

Comment: :) Yes..now its ok Actually...I just noticed @ViewBag.EquipmentList.Count works but is always = 1

Comment: @Pinch: Where by "fixed up" you mean "completely changed" so it's now not about an error at all? <sigh>

Comment: code == post  And Count is always 1, every consider a career in proof reading, i'm sure your pays better though!

Comment: I do appreciate your patience!

Comment: @Pinch: You've given *no* indication why you'd expect count not to be equal to 1. You've also given no indication of what you had to change to make the code work at all. Basically this question is now unanswerable. You've effectively said: "I've got a list, but it only ever has a single element. Why?"

Comment: i have created a situation where there were multiple returns and zero and one.

Comment: @Pinch: I'm afraid that comment is too vague to be helpful. (Multiple returns from where?) As I say in my answer: this is nothing to do with Razor any more, and we don't know enough about the data source to help. I suggest you ask a new question, ideally reverting this question to its previous form but updating it with what you had to do to get `Count` working at all.

Comment: i'll try and gather my thoughts together, your answer was well put, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

```
@ViewBag.EquipmentListNI.Count()
```

Comment: sorry but, Count' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @Pinch: it can if you're using the Linq extension method.

Comment: Just for clarity, since I got the same message @Pinch did- To use .Count(), add this to top of class: using System.Linq;